# Hide Submit Button while Waiting for Server (Binding not working?)

Tags: typescript, angular

I've got an Angular 2 form that submits data to the server asynchronously. I need to provide some visual feedback to end-users while their browser is waiting to hear back from the server, so I'd like to change the blue 'submit' button to a greyed-out 'Please wait...' button. I decided that the easiest way to do this would be to have two buttons and hide one when the other is visible.

I thought I could just put this in my model:

```
isPending: boolean = false;
```

And this on my page:

```
<button [hidden]="!isPending" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
<button [hidden]="isPending" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Please wait...</button>
```

But both buttons are always visible, regardless of the value isPending is set to.

What is the idiomatic way to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `[hidden]` with `*ngIf` like so:

```
<button *ngIf="!isPending" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
<button *ngIf="isPending" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Please wait...</button>
```

The problem is, that the `class` directives in your button tags override the `hidden` directive at runtime.

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bFXXcjxYGhWcRyTM9KIO?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: Thanks for your answer rinukkusu, now only the 'Register' button is showing. However - changing the value of 'isPending' doesn't toggle the visibility of the two buttons. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work - check out the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bFXXcjxYGhWcRyTM9KIO?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, you were on the money. I had a silly mistake elsewhere - I think that means its time for me to take a break :). Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)